# How to offline install Gnome 3 on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome3

I connect to a remote CentOS via ssh. This remote server has no GUI installed and is located in an isolated network without an access to the Internet. I need to install Gnome 3 on it. Can I download all required Gnome 3 packages to my local machine, copy them to a remote machine and install Gnome 3 there in an offline mode? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh access you should be able to copy the files, maybe with scp.  So yes, it's possible, but that's just one option.

You could also set up a yum repository with those packages on your local machine and point the remote system to that repository.

You could also download a .iso file from CentOS.org and copy it to the remote system, then mount the .iso and use its directory of package files to create a yum repo on the remote system.  I think an advantage of this variant is it would ensure you have all of the dependencies needed for Gnome.